# Ask about int array in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Code below is a simple c# function return an int array.
I would like to know how to convert it to Objective-C

```
private int[] test()
{
    int[] a = new int[2];
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
- (NSArray *)test {
    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], nil];
    return a;
}
```

Note that if we created the `NSArray` using `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:blah, blah, nil];`, we'd have to explicitly `autorelease` the array before returning it in order to avoid a memory leak. In this case, however, the `NSArray` is created using a convenience constructor, so the array is already `autorelease`d for us.

**Second Question:**

Try this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)test:(int)count {
    NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        [a insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] atIndex:i];
    }
    return [a autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit dummy example:

```
- (NSArray*) test{
  return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], nil];
}
```

Some notes:

- NSArray is a immutable type - so if you want to add/remove values you should use NSMutableArray instead
- You can store only objects in NSArray so you need to wrap them into NSNumber (or another obj-c type)
- Obj-c is a superset of C so you can freely use c-arrays in you obj-c code if you want

Answer (score 2):

Or an alternative path would be to use normal c code (is allowed in objective c):

```
int a[2]={1, 2};
```

Or in a function:

```
int *somefunc(void){
    static int a[2]={1, 2};
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of array in Objective-C: standard C arrays and Cocoa NSArrays. [C arrays](http://home.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm) hold primitive ints but are quite troublesome due to the limitations of C. [NSArrays](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) have to hold objects, but you can just wrap ints in NSNumbers and get the int value back out when you need it.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:500], [NSNumber numberWithInt:12000], nil];
```